# TypeError: delete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk' django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

i have a view in my django app which looks like following

```
class DeployedContractsList(APIView):    
    def get_Contract(self, address):
        contracts = DeployedContracts.objects.all()
        if address:
            contracts = contracts.filter(
                Q(deployed_contract_address__iexact=address)
            )
        return contracts

    def get(self, request, email, format=None):
        service_providers = self.get_queryset(email)
        serializer = DeployedContractsSerializer(service_providers, many=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data)


    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        item = self.get_Contract(address=pk)
        item.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

and i have configured my app urls in following way

```
    router = DefaultRouter()

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^(?P<email>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$', views.DeployedContractsList.as_view()),
        url(r'^(?P<pk>)/$', views.DeployedContractsList.as_view()),
        url(r'^', views.DeployedContractsList.as_view())
   ]
```

and project's urls.py i have following configurations

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^deployedcontracts', include('deployedcontracts.urls')),
]
```

but upon making a delete request by `http://127.0.0.1:8000/deployedcontracts/0xe9114368611e9f20cf46b76aa33319fc0ce0b585/` i am getting following error

[image]

despite the fact i have attached pk in request url i.e 0xe9114368611e9f20cf46b76aa33319fc0ce0b585 as it can be seen in my url. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add regular expression to url patern:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/$', views.DeployedContractsList.as_view()),
```

Comment: i tried adding regular expression as you suggested, but no luck. still getting same response.